# Tile Laplacian Filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filters, filtering, enhancement

I want to compute the output image by first dividing the image into 8*8 blocks and applying laplace filter separately and combine them but I am not getting the correct output
Here is the code:

```
I=imread('moon.tif');
figure;
imshow(I);
title('Original Image');
g=[0 1 0;1 -4 1;0 1 0];
[N, M] = size(I);
output = zeros(N,M);
for i=1:8:N
    for j=1:8:M
        a = min(i+7,N);
        b = min(j+7,M);
        img = I(i:a,j:b);
        r = imfilter(im2double(img),g);
        output(i:a,j:b) = im2double(img)-r;
    end
end
figure;
imshow(output);
```

[image]

Here is the output I am getting blocks by blocks discontinuous
But when I run this code

```
I=imread('moon.tif');
figure;
imshow(I);
title('Original Image');
g=[0 1 0;1 -4 1;0 1 0];
resp=imfilter(I,g);
output = I-resp;
figure;
imshow(output);
title('Sharpened image');
```

[image]

I am getting the correct output. How to get this by dividing the image into 8x8 blocks and combining them

Comment: Are you after how to implement image processing algorithm by image tiling or juts understanding how convolution works?

Comment: @Royi I want to apply the filter to 8*8 blocks of image and check the PSNR

Comment: Laplacian filter works in a rolling window manner (Convolution). Hence I'm asking if the `8 x 8` is for working in a tiling method? If not, what you're asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Royi yes it is

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when filtering images there are boundary effects.

If you want to work with tiles of `8x8` you need to take bigger tiles.
Assuming the filter radius is `r` (In your case `r = 1`) then the tiles should be `(8 + 2r)x(8 + 2r)`.
So in the above, take tiles of `10x10` and use only their center part.

So you process `8x8` tile by taking `10x10` window, apply the filter and return the center of `8x8` pixels.

Then you will have the same output as working on the whole image.

For code implementing the idea look at [Apply 2D Convolution on an Image Using Tiles](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81420).