# Apply 2D Convolution on an Image Using Tiles

Tags: image-processing, convolution, software-implementation

I have 2D convolution with a large input image (512x1920). I am trying to partition the image across height and width to perform this convolution as N pieces.
This would involve having an intersection between each sub-slice of the input image.
I would like to understand how to calculate this intersection for various size of stride, padding and kernel size.

Comment: See [Overlap–add method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap–add_method) and [Overlap–save method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap–save_method)

Answer (score 1):

This is called tiling in image processing.
It is used to keep better locality of the calculations and improve performance.

Assume you have image of `512x512`.
Assume we work on tiles of size `64x64`.
So we have 64 tiles in the image each covers `64x64` of the image.

In case of doing a spatial operation we don't want to have boundary issues hence we add to each tile some padding.
The size of the padding depends on the radius of the kernel used.
Assume we work using convolution with a kernel of size `11x11` then the radius of the kernel is `5` hence we need to pad the tiles with `5` pixels in each direction.

[image]

So per tile we have and input of size `74x74` and output of `64x64`.

I implemented this in Julia:

```
kernelLen = (2 * kernelRadius) + 1;
kernelNumPx = Float64(kernelLen * kernelLen);
mK      = Kernel{(-kernelRadius:kernelRadius, -kernelRadius:kernelRadius)}(@inline mW -> (sum(mW) / kernelNumPx));
mIPad   = PadImage(mI, (kernelRadius, kernelRadius));

mORef = map(mK, mIPad);
mORef = Float64.(mORef); #<! See https://github.com/stev47/StaticKernels.jl/issues/11

mO = zeros(size(mI));

# Working by the inner indices
for firstRowIdx in 1:tTileSize[1]:tSize[1], firstColIdx in 1:tTileSize[2]:tSize[2]
    lastRowIdx  = firstRowIdx + tTileSize[1] - 1;
    lastColIdx  = firstColIdx + tTileSize[2] - 1;
    
    # The padded image is basically shifted by `kernelRadius`
    firstRowIdxTile = firstRowIdx;
    lastRowIdxTile  = firstRowIdxTile + tTileSize[1] + (2 * kernelRadius) - 1;
    firstColIdxTile = firstColIdx;
    lastColIdxTile  = firstColIdxTile + tTileSize[2] + (2 * kernelRadius) - 1;
    @views map!(mK, mO[firstRowIdx:lastRowIdx, firstColIdx:lastColIdx], mIPad[firstRowIdxTile:lastRowIdxTile, firstColIdxTile:lastColIdxTile]);
end
```

The output is identical to working on the whole image:

[image]

[image]

The code is available at my [StackExchange Codes Signal Processing GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q81420` folder).